# How to find the number of items in a variable? (AppleScript)

Tags: applescript, exists

I am trying to find the number of items in a variable, I tried to create somewhat of a while loop to test if the item of the variable exists, if it does then go to the next item and test if it exists, this repeats until the item does not exist, then it displays the current item number, which should be the final item of the variable.
Here is my code:

```
    set stuff to "123456789"
    set x to "1"
    set num to item x of stuff
    if exists item x of stuff then
    repeat while exists item (x + 1) of stuff
        if exists (item x of stuff) then
            set x to (x + 1)
        else
            set num to x
        end if
    end repeat
    end if
    display dialog num
```

Currently when I run this code I get the error: 
"Can’t get item 10 of "123456789"."
Which I understand tells me that 10 is the last item of this variable but the information does me no good in the form of an error message. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### *How to find the number of items in a variable? (AppleScript)*

The clue's in the question:

```
set variable to "123456789"
return the number of items in the variable --> 9
```

[image]

As already stated by red_menace, you can also quantify data objects using the `length` property (for `list`, `record`, or `text` objects), or by using the **`count`** command, which is superfluous in my view as it ends up accessing the `length` property anyway.

Comment: Ahh thank you very much, clearly I am an applescript amateur since I had no idea this  was possible xD.

Answer (score 0):

The AppleScript command `count` counts the number of elements in an object, for example `count of stuff`.  In addition, classes such as `list`, `record`, and `text` also have a `length` property, for example `length of stuff`.

```
set stuff to "this is a test"
set x to 0
repeat with anItem in (get items of stuff)
    set x to x + 1 -- just using x to count
    log anItem
end repeat
display dialog "Number of items is " & x & return & "Count is " & (count stuff) & return & "Length is " & (length of stuff)
```

See the [AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH208-SW1) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the information, this opened up so many new possibilities for what I will be able to do in future projects, I know I will use it!